# getting a spec file instead of a exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to generate a exe with pyinstaller
with this command

```
C:\Python\Python37\Scripts>pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed "filepath\file.py"
```

pyistaller generate a spec file, how can I get a exe ?

Comment: Have you checked the `dist` folder created by pyinstaller when you run that command? That's usually where the executable would be found.

Comment: its right there, thanks